# How do you get a StarCluster AMI to work with IPython 0.13?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ipython, starcluster, qiime

I tried upgrading IPython on two different StarCluster AMIs (their default 64-bit Ubuntu 11.10 and the QIIME 1.5 image). In either case, when I start up my cluster the initialization script hangs at 'Waiting for JSON connector file...'. I logged in to the instances and, indeed, even though an ipcluster daemon was running, it hadn't written any JSON files to profile_default/security.

Maybe this is a difference between where IPython 0.12 and 0.13 put their connector files? Or maybe the updated ipcluster hangs for some reason? It doesn't appear to have any meaningful logs so I'm not sure how to figure out what's going on. Has anyone had luck upgrading a StarCluster AMI to use the newest IPython? If so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably aware of this by now but for others out there:

There's a work-around posted in IPython's issue tracker and an issue was posted to incorporate the work-around in the ipcluster plugin in StarCluster:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2171#issuecomment-7153192

https://github.com/jtriley/StarCluster/issues/127

Comment: This is now fixed in the latest github code and will be included in the next release.